# How can I save NeoVim config?

Tags: neovim

`:help nvim-config` suggests using `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/nvim` to store configuration files. But, when I go to `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` and do `ls -a` there isn't any `nvim` directory.

What should I do, and how do I create my first basic NeoVim config file?

P.S. I'm using NeoVim on WSL.

Comment: Just create the directory and put the files there.

Answer (score 0):

To start your Neovim configuration, create an initial configuration file `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/nvim/init.lua`

Then you could use a basic Neovim configuration as [A Basic Stable IDE config for Neovim](https://github.com/LunarVim/nvim-basic-ide) (GIt repository) to start yours: options, plugins, keymaps...